# Matching two columns of two different data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For two different data frames, one with unique names and id and another with those names in a repetitive format.

In a pandas data frame, how do you match two different data frames and generate the repetitive correspondent ids?

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBMeX.png)

Comment: Please repeat your answer with your code clearly

Comment: upload code not images... read guidelines of stackoverflow

Comment: Can't really write a solution without code, but you probably want `.loc` and `.isin`, something along the lines of `df.loc[df.Names.isin(df1.Names), 'stationID']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```

The code above join the two dataframes along columns